# Error while installing keras

Tags: installation, python, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install keras via pip but the `pip install keras` command
is throwing me some errors:

`Retrying (Retry(total=N, connect=None, read=None, Redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.'), error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired',))': /simple/keras/`

repeated five times, with *`N`* equal to `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` and `0`;
then

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for keras
```

(I'm behind a web proxy). 
Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this?

<sup>[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPVE.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First Try to uninstall it by using this command `pip uninstall keras`. Then again try to install it with this command `pip install keras`. Still you getting same error then try to Install `keras` in [Anaconda Environment](https://medium.com/i-want-to-be-the-very-best/installing-keras-tensorflow-using-anaconda-for-machine-learning-44ab28ff39cb).  Hope this Helpful and will clear your Doubt !